# Locker booking system db design help

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, database-design, mysql-5.7

Good afternoon

I'm trying to design the database for a locker booking system but being the first time that i design such kind of db i'm facing many issues and doubt that i cannot solve myself as i can't make it so clear in my mind.

The idea behind is the following :

We'll host some smart lockers in our shops and wants to make users able to reserve a box of this locker online in advance.

The user will access our ecommerce, choose the locker location, and than he will be able to make an availability check by inserting in the form the request detail (deposit_date, duration, box_type, box_quantity).

At this point, if there are box available according to the user request, i will redirect them to the check out page, else, i will ask them to look for a new date.

So far I've deisgned 5 tables as follow :

- locations
- boxes
- reservations
- users
- payments

See below a image of the design :

[image]

The relations i imagined are :

- One location has many boxes
- One box has many reservations
- One user has many reservations
- One payment belgs to one reservation

But I feel like I'm missing something, could anybody help me to understand what is missing in this design?

Hope to receive an help, thank you so much.

Gianmarco

Comment: Welcome to DBA Stack Exchange. This is rather a broad question so probably won't get an answer beyond this. You'll discover if you missed anything when you start to code it. I'd consider `location_id`, `box_number` as a composite primary key however its not critical. Nothing else obviously wrong. Stick to a single DB next time. Using MariaDB's [application time periods](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/) is a good way to make the booking of items have time constraints enforced.

Comment: Try to write the `SELECTs` you will need.  That is likely to give you clues of Schema issues.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your replies. I'll try to code it and check where i criticity in it! Thanks again for your suggestions :)